# remove files older than 4 days - DONT WORK

Tags: bash

i have a little script to remove my daily backups

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +4 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
```

and cronjob every 10 days at 5am.

```
0 5 */10 * * /mnt/md0/it/BackupData/removeOldFiles.sh >> /home/myuser/myscript.log 2>&1
```

but this is output of today

[image]

So dont know why this not working

Comment: In which directory do you want to remove files?

Comment: Your command doesn't do older than 4 days, it does the oldest 4. `find . -mtime +4 -delete`

Comment: As jordanm says, the tool to use is `find`.

Comment: Do not expect to have 1 file per day, weird situations do happen.  With `find` you are much more certain to delete proper files.  And it will handle filenames with spaces or special characters correctly as well.

Comment: @jordanm understand, so if i have cron every 10th days, my script will remove 10,9.8 and 7 and your 5,6,7,8,9,10, am i right?

Comment: Nope, run the command in cron every day.  It will always delete the files older than 4 days.  So after the first run, it will delete 1 file a day.